# jQuery- Use variable name in each loop to name new variable

Tags: jquery

I have an array of items, and I am trying to assign a variable name based on each of the array's item names. For example, if the array has the values:

```
var thearray = {};
thearray['0'] = 'car';
thearray['1'] = 'boat';
thearray['2'] = 'truck';
```

I want to end up with three variables, named `car_output, boat_output, truck_output`.

They will all contain the same data. Here is how I'm trying to do it:

```
$.each(thearray, function(index, value) { 
    var value+'_output' = 'stuff...'; // something not right
});
```

Something is not right with the way I'm trying to name each variable. Any ideas?

Comment: 'var value+'_output' = 'stuff...';` ??? why is there `+` sign and a constant `'_output'`? The LHS should be a variable only

Comment: @JROB - Look at bala answer it is perfect answer for your question

Comment: @JqueryKing Thanks... once I get the arrays loaded, I can't get them onto the page: `$('#'+value).html(value+'_output');`. It's just showing the actual word, for example "car_output" and not what the var "car_output" actually is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick. The secret is to use the global `window` object like an array, in order to create dynamic variable names.

```
var thearray = {};
thearray['0'] = 'car';
thearray['1'] = 'boat';
thearray['2'] = 'truck';

$.each(thearray, function(index, value) { 
    window[value+'_output'] = 'stuff...';
});

console.log(car_output); // "stuff..."
```

Comment: One problem I'm having is trying to output the variable contents into a div: `$('#'+value).html(value+'_output');`... it's outputting the text, for example `car_output`, and not what the variable `car_output` actually holds.

Answer (score 0):

you can do using array,

```
var user_types = ["car","boat","truck"];
var types = {};

$.each(user_types, function( index, value ){
  types[value+"_output"] = 'The value of dynamic variable, val';
});

console.log(types);
```

i hope this help you..

Answer (score 0):

Try to create an `object` dynamically to store the relevant values, please don't use `window object` to store the values since it is a **clumsy** way.

```
var thearray = {};
thearray['0'] = 'car';
thearray['1'] = 'boat';
thearray['2'] = 'truck';

var obj={};
$.each(thearray, function (index, value) {
    obj[value+"_output"]="stuff";
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/h45A5/54/)

Comment: @Downvoter: Care to comment.? what's wrong in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you wanted. it's working as you wanted.

```
var user_types = ["car","boat","truck"];
var types = {};

$.each(user_types, function( index, value ){
  types[value+'_Output'] = value;
});

console.log(types);
```

see jsfiddle link  http://jsfiddle.net/C23U8/1/